# Website BaseDirectory in during Initialize method of ProtectedConfigurationProvider for ASP.NET (.NET framework 4.5)

Tags: asp.net, configuration, .net-4.5, provider

**Goal**:  Find the BaseDirectory of a running ASP.NET web application with .NET Framework 4.5 during a call to the Initialize method of a class inheriting from ProtectedConfigurationProvider.

**Problem**: The .NET Framework 4.5 has changed which Domain a ProtectedConfigurationProvider class runs under (and perhaps also when the class gets called in the lifecycle of an application?)

Prior to installing .NET Framework 4.5, could be retrieved during the Initialize or Decrypt methods of a class inheriting from ProtectedConfigurationProvider by using "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory".   This would resolve to something along the lines of "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\"

After installing .NET Framework 4.5, during the Initialize or Decrypt methods  "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" resolves to something along the lines of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\".

**Use Case**: Redirect calls for configuration data from web.config/app.config to custom config files in the application directory with a custom "ProtectedConfigurationProvider" class.  (ex. http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Redirecting-Configuration-with-a-Custom-Provider.id-291932.html  or  https://github.com/kellyhughes/ConfigPTFE).  This is used in a config node with the "configProtectionProvider" attribute.   This library is being consumed by various application types (ex. winforms, wpf, windows services, web applications.) The issue mentioned above only occurs during the context of a web application.

**Note**:  Most objects I know to fall back on to glean info from are null at the point this method gets called.  For example, HttpContext and Server.MapPath can't help because they don't seem to exist at this point.  And yes, i also know there are other ways to separate config files from the main config.  This custom library provides additional features not provided by using things like the "file" or "configSource" attributes.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem when using custom ProtectedConfigurationProvider to encrypt appSettings section (note that other sections, like NHibernate/Spring's <persistence> worked fine). The framework could not load locate the assembly, because it was looking for it in c:\(...)\inetsrv folder.